# Animal Crossing: Wild World Communication Error

Tags: animal-crossing-wild-world

I keep getting an error that says that I've been disconnected when doing DS to DS communications. There is no error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly there are many things contributing to a communication error, so many in fact that there are very little you can do about them. I've been playing *Wild Word* since it came out with various people, and we haven't found the source of the problem. However, there are some things you can do to reduce the frequency of these errors:

- When playing, put your DS down on a surface and avoid moving it too much with respect to the other DS's around.
- Keep your DS away from sources of interference, such as microwaves and even other wireless devices (such as laptops, cellphones and routers).
- Make sure to not move out of range of communication when playing over Wi-Fi.

Like I said, these disconnections are frequent at best, and require some preventive measures. Despite those measures, we could not prevent connection issues completely.

I hope this helps alleviate your problem a bit!